# Exception when Using TestRestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, testing, spring-boot

I have ordinary SpringBoot application with custom auth filter which works normally.

But I have problem when using TestRestTemplate in integration test.

I would like to check here if user with wrong creditials cant login.
But Instead of ResponseEntity with 401 status I got Exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:795)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:779)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:512)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:454)
    at cz.angular.security.basic.rest.AuthorizeControllerTest.userWithWrongCreditials(AuthorizeControllerTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1280)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:552)
    ... 42 more
```

Internally spring throws 
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException but in real application usage its translated to json response.

When using curl I got normal response.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"user","password":"password-wrong"}' http://localhost:8080/login
{"timestamp":"2014-12-07T10:07:27.166+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","exception":"org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/login"}
```

Test code is here:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:9999")
public class AuthorizeControllerTest {

  public static final String LOCALHOST = "http://localhost:9999";

...

  @Test
  public void userWithWrongCreditials() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate rest = new TestRestTemplate();

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
    credentials.setName("user");
    credentials.setPassword("password-wrong");

    ResponseEntity<Map> response =
      rest.exchange(
        LOCALHOST + "/login",
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new HttpEntity<Credentials>(credentials),
        Map.class);

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());
  }
}
```

Whole project can be seen in repository

https://bitbucket.org/winsik/security-token-stackoverflow/

Where you can see both passing tests and the failing one in AuthorizeControllerTest.

I have try a lot of things like setting Content type and so on but with no luck.
I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that is the `TestRestTemplate` from Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes its TestRestTemplate from spring boot. 

I will try to provide full code soon, maybe there is some problem in Filter implementation but I am curious why Application works as expected (Return 401 when wrong password is given)

Comment: @DaveSyer I have edited question and added repository with whole code.

https://bitbucket.org/winsik/security-token-stackoverflow/

Where you can see both passing tests and the failing one in AuthorizeControllerTest.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need the Apache HTTP client to be able to handle errors yourself with `TestRestTemplate`. This worked for me with your project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

(I also removed the duplicated junit, mockito and spring-test dependencies.)

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. So if i get it properly httpclient will take place of default httpClient in TestRestTemplate?

Comment: Ok, you saved my time. Thanks a lot. But, why the hell this trick solve the problem?!

Comment: @Dave is it still true in Spring 5? In RestTemplate:741 `ResourceAccessException` seems to always thrown when an `IOException` is caught

Comment: I don’t think anything fundamentally changed. N.B. this question was about `TestRestTemplate`.

Comment: All I had to do was drop this dependency in and suddenly this exception went away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jackson will know how to convert JSON to `Object`. Try `Map` or something?

Comment: In successfull login test I use UserInfo object, which of course works.

Here in wrong login test I have tried also Map/LinkedHashMap/String, Object was my last try, but result is always same.

Comment: Maybe you should update the question to be closer to something that might work (i.e. use `Map` for response type)?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

**Reference** : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21321

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());   

      restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
       public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException{
           HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode(); 
           return statusCode.series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR; 
       }
     });
```